# How to extract data from my sql in a web application asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have created model of the table present in my database (MYsql) and i don't understant why some property of the model are created with an interrogative point written after the name' s property in the table class( example: public DateTime? dataChiusura { get; set; }) and why this property is not present in the model class?...Below the code of this class to have an example.
And after in asp.net MVC where should i write the query to extract data (list of object with the structure of the model)?

Thank you for your help!!

```
namespace TCA3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("nicolas.ticket")]
    public partial class ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int idTicket { get; set; }

        [StringLength(45)]
        public string codiceTicket { get; set; }

        [StringLength(45)]
        public string azienda { get; set; }

        public DateTime? dataApertura { get; set; }

        public DateTime? dataChiusura { get; set; }

        public sbyte? aperto { get; set; }

        [StringLength(45)]
        public string operaioTicket { get; set; }
    }
}




-----------------------------
namespace TCA3
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class Model1 : DbContext
    {
        public Model1()
            : base("name=Model1")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ticket> ticket { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ticket>()
                .Property(e => e.codiceTicket)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ticket>()
                .Property(e => e.azienda)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ticket>()
                .Property(e => e.operaioTicket)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The interrogation says that that property is nullable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

For the other questions, maybe you should show more of what you have or what do you whant to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want extract a list of object ticket but i am still learning the MVC pattern in asp.net and i don' t know if i must write the query in the controller or if there are better architectural solution.

Comment: MVC is a pattern designed to handle different responsibilities. Model, View, Controller. You should read this to get a better understanding of "what goes where." https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-basics-of-mvc-architecture/

Comment: thank you ...i have already read that article but i don't understand where i must put the code to interact with db

Comment: Then I suggest you find some sample applications for ASP.NET MVC that make use of Entity Framework and see how they do it.

Comment: I suggest you go through the Asp.net mvc get started document.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/ Use this demo to understand the design pattern and workflow of MVC.